# Getting JWS Token is working with curl but not with Java

Tags: java, curl, https, apache-httpclient-4.x

Here is what I am doing with curl:

```
curl -d "username=<user>&password=<pass>" -X POST https://example.com/wp-json/api/v1/token
```

This working like a charm and I am receiving the token.
Here is what curl sending:

```
POST https://example.com/wp-json/api/v1/token HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
Accept: */*
Content-Length: <length>
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

username=<user>&password=<pass>
```

With Java I am receiving code 403.
Here is debug output of HttpClient:

```
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "POST /wp-json/api/v1/token HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 45[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: www.example.com[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_121)[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "username=<user>&password=<pass>"
```

I don't see here significant difference between curl and java.
Who knows what I am doing wrong here?

Here is my current java code:

```
public void getToken(URI url, String username, String password) {
        HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity("username=" + username + "&password=" + password, ContentType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

        HttpHost target = new HttpHost(url.getHost(), 443, "https");

        SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.createSystemDefault();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                sslcontext, new String[] { "TLSv1.2", "SSLv3" }, null,
                SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());

        Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.INSTANCE)
                .register("https", sslConnectionSocketFactory)
                .build();

        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new 
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory)
                .setConnectionManager(cm)
                .build();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);

        int statusCode = 0;
        try (CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(target, httpPost)) {
            statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            //parse response here
        }
}
```

The solution was pretty simple:
one friend of me told me that I sould remove "www" from url.
And yet, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was amazingly simple (and unexpected): after I removed "www" part from URL it started to work!!!